# Xcode 10.0 error requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "ReleaseForRunning"

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

When I building my app for the phone this error prompts-up 
Spending the whole day finding a solution. hope anyone can help
Im googling for answers for 1 day and still no answers

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you have set your Apple dev account in Preferences > Accounts. Then, go to the project settings (by clicking the blue project icon from your left sidebar). Then in `General` tab under `Signing` (make sure you have selected your `Unity-iPhone` target from the left list) you have to provide a provision profile (select your `Team`. If you have privileges in the account Xcode can generate the profiles for you).

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of your error message into your question.  This makes it easier for us to find and research your issue.